# Bulk update and return Id of failed updates in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bulkupdate

```
{
events:
[
{"id": "1"}
{"id": "2"}
]
attributes:
[
{
"field": "field1"
"value": "value1"
}
{
"field": "field2"
"value": "value2"
}
]
}
```

For the above input i would like to update column `"field": "field1"` of  row `"id": "1"` with  `"value": "value1"` .

But in case of partial error I should send back a list of failed `id` .

How to get this list of failed `id` in JPA/Hibernate bulk update  ?

One way to do this is parse the list one by one and do a `transactional` update for each `id` one by one , in case of exception in DAO call, catch the exception and store this particular `id` in the partial failed list .

But this feels like a brute force way of doing it, does JPA provide a better way to do bulk update and return the list of failed `id` ?

Comment: How can it "fail"? Usually, an exception causes the TX to be marked as rollback only.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a transaction for every update is not efficient. So as you correctly said, you should use batching. [Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) is a good article on how to do it. You will find there that only one transaction is created before updates/inserts.

In case the whole batch fails, it's possible to find [which statement failed in the batch](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-find-which-statement-failed-in-a-jdbc-batch-update/). `java.sql.BatchUpdateException` provides you [a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html#getUpdateCounts--) for this.

So i'd advise you to have batch updates/inserts block of code, with `catch(BatchUpdateException)`, where you can process it individually as a fallback.